# Difference between GTK theme and GNOME shell theme?

Tags: themes, gnome-shell, gtk

I'm using GNOME Shell and I'd like to know what a GTK theme changes that a GNOME shell theme doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A GNOME shell theme will change the actual shell, i.e. buttons in the shell, colors in the shell, etc. GTK themes change the theming available to gtk applications. So basically, shell themes are themes for the shell, gtk themes are themes for applications.