# How do I install Cinnamon themes on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, themes, cinnamon, permissions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to theme the Cinnamon Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121387/how-to-theme-the-cinnamon-desktop)

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04, but I prefer Cinnamon. I installed the

ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-nightly

And Cinnamon works. Some of the icons are blank. If I go to the cinnamon-spices website and download a theme...I'm told to extract it into the `/usr/share/themes` directory.

When I attempt this, I get an error that says:
"You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder 'file:///usr/share/themes'".

I assume that since I'm unable to log in as root, that there's another way to accomplish this?

How?